# Do mathematical operations on arbitrarily many dictionaries and numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to do the following:

- take an arbitrary number of arguments that are dictionaries or numbers
- of the arguments that are dictionaries, check that they all have the same keys (else error)
- do something like

```
    for key in dict:
            out[key] = product(dict1[key],number2,dict2[key],etc.)
```

where if an argument is a number, it pretends 'as if' it is a dictionary with that number as value for every key. (Of course, this could be `sum` too instead of `product`).

Ideally this would be a library but I could use hand-written functions. So far I haven't been able to write anything that works for more than two arguments.

For example, suppose my input is:

```
a = {
    'Burkina' : 100,
    'Chad': 50
}

b = 2
```

For two arguments, I think this works:

```
def p(a,b):
    out = {}
    try:
        for key in a:
            try:
                out[key] = a[key]*b[key]
            except TypeError:
                out[key] = a[key]*b
    except TypeError:
        for key in b:
            try:
                out[key] = a[key]*b[key]
            except TypeError:
                out[key] = a*b[key]
    for key in out:
        print(key,out[key])
```

But this approach would need a longer and longer function for more arguments. So that can't be right. Then I tried to do this with `*args`:

```
def p(*args):
    out = {}
    for arg in args:
        try:
            for key in arg:
                try:
                    out[key] = a[key]*b[key]
                except TypeError:
                    out[key] = a[key]*b
        except TypeError:
            for key in args:
                try:
                    out[key] = a[key]*b[key]
                except TypeError:
                    out[key] = a*b[key]
        for key in out:
            print(key,out[key])
```

But this got TypeErrors, and my head started spinning.

Edited to add: if all inputs are numbers, I want to return a number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `isinstance` instead of handling exceptions to check if the argument is a number or a dict:

```
def func(*args):
    out = {}
    factor = 1
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, dict):
            if not out:
                out = arg.copy()
            elif out.keys() != arg.keys():
                raise KeyError('not same keys')
            else:
                for key in out:
                    out[key] *= arg[key]
        else:
            factor *= arg
    for key in out:
        out[key] *= factor
    if out:
        return out
    return factor


print(
    func(
        {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2},
        3,
        {'key1': 10, 'key2': 20},
        4
    )
)

print(func(2, 3))

# result:
# {'key1': 120, 'key2': 480}
# 6
```

Comment: Great, but assumes there is at least one dictionary in the input argument list.  I don't know if that's a guarantee the problem left out.   But, func(2, 3) returns {}, rather than 6.

Comment: @DarrylG `func` is written to always return dictionary. Returning 6 from `func(2, 3)` can cause problems on the "client side" which uses this function.

Comment: let's assume at least one dictionary is an assumption the poster left out.  Or, the poster needs to specify what he expects returned in the edge case of func(2, 3).

Comment: Good point, DarrylG. If all inputs are numbers, I want to return a number.

Comment: @tmksitt I edited my answer so the function returns number if there is no dict in arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that would work, using some of Python's "functional" tools.

The actual multiplication is done using [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), using [operator.mul](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) as the multiplication operator. This could easily be replaced with another operator from the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module if you wanted the function to perform a different operation.

A few caveats:

- The function handles non-dictionary arguments by replacing them with a dictionary with all keys equal to the non-dictionary argument.  This might be a problem if you plan to handle *really big* dictionaries, or parameter lists with a *lot* of non-dictionary items.
- The function builds lists of the its arguments and the arguments that are dictionaries; again this could be a problem for very large inputs.
- It does not check that the arguments are all of an acceptable type.

```py
import functools
import operator


def p(*args):
    args = list(args)
    dicts = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict), args))
    if not dicts:
        # Either there are no arguments, or they all numbers.
        return functools.reduce(operator.mul, args, 0)
    keys = dicts[0].keys()
    if not all(d.keys() == keys for d in dicts):
        raise ValueError(f'Not all dicts have matching keys.')
    for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        # Assume "number" means int or float, but could be complex, or Decimal?
        # See the numbers module for numeric abstract base classes.
        if isinstance(arg, (float, int)):
            args[i] = dict.fromkeys(keys, arg)
    out = {k: functools.reduce(operator.mul, (a[k] for a in args)) for k in keys}
    return out
```